# googlecredential no such method error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-plus-one

I am trying to construct a google credential object so that I can use google plus Oauth, but keep getting an error. My client-id and client-secret are exactly as given in my developer console, so I don't think it's that.

My code is:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setTransport(TRANSPORT)
        .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).build();
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ConnectServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.getRefreshListeners()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:394)
    at com.google.gplus.ConnectServlet.doPost(ConnectServlet.java:128)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And here are the relevant jars I'm using:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev64-1.13.2-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev50-1.17.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any input would be much appreciated. I googled it and didn't see anything similar.

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are mixing clients veriions

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>**1.19.0**</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>**v2-rev50-1.17.0-rc**</version>
  </dependency>
```

Use the same version for all google client libraries.